# Why does SSRS Dataset Query Designer "rewrite" my query when I paste SQL from SSMS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Surely this question has been asked and answered before, I must just be searching for the wrong terms..
When I design an SSRS report, I always write and test my queries in SSMS first. And I do mean write them, none of this new-fangled Query Designer. (yeah, yeah grandpa we know; barefoot, through the snow, uphill both ways...)
When I paste the query into the dataset creator window in SSRS (whether directly into the text box or into the Query designer - it nearly always re writes my query. 
Sometimes it adds table aliases where I really should have done so myself - fine. 
Sometimes it gets the aliases wrong and breaks my query! But other times it is expanding something I wrote and turning into an unreadable mess!

For Example, if I write a query with the following where clause:

```
WHERE    (DimDate.FullDate >= @StartDate1) AND (DimDate.FullDate <= @EndDate2) 
AND ((FNSE.CategoryID = @InclProductCategory) OR (@InclProductCategory = 2))
AND ((AcctMgr.Initials = @AcctMgr) OR (@AcctMgr = 'ALL') )
AND (((CASE SPCredit.BusinessUnit WHEN 'Pediatric' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = @InclUnitsCreditTo) OR
(@InclUnitsCreditTo = 2))
```

SSRS expands that where clause into:

```
WHERE     (DimDate.FullDate >= @StartDate1) AND (DimDate.FullDate <= @EndDate2) 
AND (FNSE.CategoryID = @InclProductCategory) 
AND (AcctMgr.Initials = @AcctMgr) 
AND ((CASE SPCredit.BusinessUnit WHEN 'Pediatric' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = @InclUnitsCreditTo) 
OR
(DimDate.FullDate >= @StartDate1) AND (DimDate.FullDate <= @EndDate2) 
AND (AcctMgr.Initials = @AcctMgr) 
AND ((CASE SPCredit.BusinessUnit WHEN 'Pediatric' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = @InclUnitsCreditTo) 
AND (@InclProductCategory = 2) 
OR
(DimDate.FullDate >= @StartDate1) AND (DimDate.FullDate <= @EndDate2) 
AND (FNSE.CategoryID = @InclProductCategory) 
AND ((CASE SPCredit.BusinessUnit WHEN 'Pediatric' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = @InclUnitsCreditTo) 
AND (@AcctMgr = 'ALL') 
OR
(DimDate.FullDate >= @StartDate1) AND (DimDate.FullDate <= @EndDate2) 
AND ((CASE SPCredit.BusinessUnit WHEN 'Pediatric' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) = @InclUnitsCreditTo) 
AND (@InclProductCategory = 2) 
AND (@AcctMgr = 'ALL') 
OR
(DimDate.FullDate >= @StartDate1) AND (DimDate.FullDate <= @EndDate2) 
AND (FNSE.CategoryID = @InclProductCategory) 
AND (AcctMgr.Initials = @AcctMgr) 
AND (@InclUnitsCreditTo = 2) 
OR
(DimDate.FullDate >= @StartDate1) AND (DimDate.FullDate <= @EndDate2) 
AND (AcctMgr.Initials = @AcctMgr) 
AND (@InclProductCategory = 2) 
AND (@InclUnitsCreditTo = 2) 
OR
(DimDate.FullDate >= @StartDate1) AND (DimDate.FullDate <= @EndDate2) 
AND (FNSE.CategoryID = @InclProductCategory) 
AND (@AcctMgr = 'ALL') 
AND (@InclUnitsCreditTo = 2) 
OR
(DimDate.FullDate >= @StartDate1) AND (DimDate.FullDate <= @EndDate2) 
AND (@InclProductCategory = 2) 
AND (@AcctMgr = 'ALL') 
AND (@InclUnitsCreditTo = 2)
```

I get that these are logically equivilent statements - however the SSSRS rewrite is much harder to read, or go back and modify in the future. Also just for giggles I pasted both versions of the full query into SSMS, provided the exact same parameter values, and ran the estimated execution plan for both... they were not the same, mine was faster (based on looking at the subtree cost only, i'm by no means an expert on query plans)

Can anyone point me to why this happens, and if there is a way to prevent it - other than using stored procs for every SSRS dataset?

Comment: what's the downside to using stored procedures? I find it easier to debug, and make changes without loading the report up.

Comment: No downside really, to me. Just no one else on my BI team has had formal SQL training or has experience working with Stored procs. So when I can avoid using them, I like to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just change the query to TEXT (during the query section - you will see the "query type" normally being stored procedure) and just paste it in?  If it insists, you can also download the RDL and then update the "Datasource" section manually and just re-upload it and overwrite.  I also walk through the snow...

Comment: Thank you for spelling it out. Turns out what I was really doing was pasting into the query designer every time, and not setting it to edit text first. It is only when SSRS tries to display query visualy that it rewrite the query in the process.
Sometimes, you really have to pay attention to what you're doing.

Comment: Glad to hear all is working.  It is why I always say that Microsoft do brilliant server products, but their front ends really let them down (I am pro MS).  Even SSIS is so clunky and temperamental.  Maybe with Power-shell, the real experts can do some nice front-ends.

Comment: The above was taught to me my @RichardVivian, who you will see around SO.

Comment: The "Edit as Text" window still rewrites my queries, into something completely different, adding in column names that don't exist...

Comment: nope nevermind. the view i was querying had the wrong column name.